# VB redeclare as different type

Tags: vb.net, declaration

Can I change the variable type by declare it again in the code. Like...

```
Dim x As New DEV_CLASS
If environment = "UAT" Then
   Dim x As New UAT_CLASS
End If

x.something1
x.something2
x.something3
```

Comment: No. I recommend you use an interface.

Comment: Please make an effort to post properly formatted and syntactically correct code.  What you have posted will not even compile. VB does not have an _EndIF_ keyword.  It has _End If_  (with a space).

Answer (score 2):

As @TyCobb pointed out, use an interface

```
 Dim x As MyInterface

 If environment = "UAT" Then
     x = New UAT_CLASS
 Else
     x = New DEV_CLASS
     'DirectCast(x, DEV_CLASS).SomeOtherDevMethod()
 End If

 x.Method1()
 x.Method2()
```

Class and interface definition:

```
Public Interface MyInterface

    Sub Method1()
    Sub Method2()

End Interface

Public Class DEV_CLASS
    Implements MyInterface

    Public Sub Method1() Implements MyInterface.Method1

    End Sub

    Public Sub Method2() Implements MyInterface.Method2

    End Sub

    Public Sub SomeOtherDevMethod()

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class UAT_CLASS
    Implements MyInterface

    Public Sub Method1() Implements MyInterface.Method1

    End Sub

    Public Sub Method2() Implements MyInterface.Method2

    End Sub

End Class
```